# Why do the authors of this paper disappear?

Tags: bibtex

MWE:

```
\documentclass[referee]{svjour3}

\usepackage[english]{babel}

\begin{document}
\cite{yang2008,yang2010}

\bibliographystyle{IEEEtran}
\bibliography{IEEEabrv,bibfile_test}
\end{document}
```

The cls file can be obtained from [here](http://static.springer.com/sgw/documents/468198/application/zip/LaTeX_DL_468198_220118.zip).

bibfile_test file:

```
@article{yang2010,
  title={An analytical continuous-curvature path-smoothing algorithm},
  author={Yang, Kwangjin and Sukkarieh, Salah},
  journal={IEEE Transactions on Robotics},
  volume={26},
  number={3},
  pages={561--568},
  year={2010},
  publisher={IEEE}
}

@inproceedings{yang2008,
  title={3D smooth path planning for a UAV in cluttered natural environments},
  author={Yang, Kwangjin and Sukkarieh, Salah},
  booktitle={Intelligent Robots and Systems, 2008. IROS 2008. IEEE/RSJ International Conference on},
  pages={794--800},
  year={2008},
  organization={IEEE}
}
```

Resulting PDF:

[image]

Why do the authors disappear in the second case? How do I fix it (short of manually editing the bib file)?

Comment: The authors don't "disappear" -- their names are replaced by `---------`. That's what the `IEEEtran` bibliography style is programmed to do with entries whose authors are repeated from the preceding entry. If you don't like this look, start looking for a different bibliography style.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They are just the same as in the previous entry in list. This is how IEEEtran style formats the references.